# Extracting JSON arrays and inserting them as separate rows in a new database

Tags: sqlite, sqlite-json1

I have a database which uses JSON to store values.

```
CREATE TABLE JSON(name TEXT, value TEXT);
```

I am trying to convert this into a native format.

```
CREATE TABLE NATIVE(name TEXT, KEY1, KEY2, KEY3);
```

The JSON format looks like this:

```
[
    {"key1":value1, "key2":value2, "key3":value3},
    {"key1":value4, "key2":value5, "key3":value6},
    ....
]
```

For the above example, I am trying to come up with a query using `INSERT INTO NATIVE (name, KEY1, KEY2, KEY3) SELECT <something> FROM JSON` to produce this table:

```
+------+---------+--------+--------+
| TEXT | KEY1    | KEY2   | KEY3   |
+------+---------+--------+--------+
| TEXT | VALUE1  | VALUE2 | VALUE3 |
| TEXT | VALUE4  | VALUE5 | VALUE3 |
...
+------+---------+--------+--------+
```

I have been using [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/json1.html) for other tables which use simple objects.  So for instance when I have values which are objects and not arrays of objects I can use `json_extract` for each field.

For an array I think I am supposed to use `json_each` but I am having a hard time figuring out how to apply it to this specific problem.

Comment: Which column in the `JSON` table contains the actual JSON content?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution:

```
INSERT INTO NATIVE (name, key1, key2, key3)
SELECT name, json_extract(x.value, '$.key1') 
           , json_extract(x.value, '$.key2')
           , json_extract(x.value, '$.key3')
FROM JSON, json_each(JSON.value) AS x;
```

The trick is that `json_each` when used in conjunction with the table containing JSON and a SELECT is returning rows in which there are fields called `key` and `value` which contain each key and value.  It is then possible to call `json_extract` in the select to pick individual fields out, which can then be inserted into the new table.

Answer (score 0):

We can try using the `JSON_EXTRACT` function from the `json1` extension library, along with an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO NATIVE(name TEXT, KEY1, KEY2, KEY3)
SELECT
    name,
    JSON_EXTRACT(value, '$.key1'),
    JSON_EXTRACT(value, '$.key2'),
    JSON_EXTRACT(value, '$.key3')
FROM JSON;
```

This assumes that it is the `value` column in `JSON` which contains the raw JSON.  If not, then replace `value` in the above query by whatever column contains the JSON content.

Comment: this works if the value contains an object.  however, the value contains an array of objects.  i think i've stumbled on a possible solution though, i'll post it shortly.